# Can someone identify this fan switch (PHOTO)

Tags: switch, fans

This fan switch has become unresponsive.  Looking to figure out whether it needs a battery or is self-powered.  Would be great to get a make/model ID, manual or simply an answer on how to address.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Progress Lighting in-wall remote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002O3VECY).

It's designed for places that only have a single circuit between the switch and the fan/light combo. Constant power is fed directly thru the switch to the fan. There is stand-alone a receiver module in the fan canopy.  The "switch" send wireless remote signals just like a handheld remote would.